# Can a pyinstaller generated exe access user-created input files?

Tags: python, excel, pyinstaller, openpyxl, py2exe

I'm using Openpyxl to read in a user-generated excel workbook, do some calculations, and update the workbook with the results. I'd prefer compiling my Python code to an exe, so it can be easily run on some coworkers' Windows machines without having to install Python. I know pyinstaller can access images/other static data files at the time of compiling the exe. I need to be able to access the excel file not at the time of compiling, but when the end user runs the program. Is this possible?

Comment: The short answer is no unless you generate the specific Excel file within openpyxl 
from scratch which can be tedious if not impossible depending on the spreadsheet, or you need to give them some kind of access to your spreadsheet.

Comment: They have access to the spreadsheet already. They fill it out, click myprogram.exe, then get the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**: a frozen python executable can read/write other files just like a regular python script can. The only caveat is that relative file paths have to be defined slightly differently in the to-be-frozen python code (as explained in the  [PyInstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html)).